# Why do we need to use sysfunc when we call a SAS function inside a SAS macro

Tags: sas

I saw this piece of code in my project:

```
%let num = test;
%let x=%sysfunc(trim(&num));
```

Why could not  I write:

```
%let x= %trim(&num);
```

Why did I need to use sysfunc?

Under what circumstances can I call a function inside a macro without using sysfunc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the sysfunc(), the expression will not be evaluated. You will not be assigning the value of the expression trim(&num) to the macrovariable, but rather the whole expression.

If you want to store the result of an expression, you need to execute that function with sysfunc()

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514sysfunc.htm

Comment: Thanks. Why we need the % sign in front of sysfunc but not in front of trim?

Comment: The argument to sysfunc is the precise code that sysfunc should execute as though it were not in a macro - so it interprets trim correctly

Answer (score 2):

The `trim()` function is part of the *SAS Language*. Without the `%sysfunc()` *macro function*, `trim()` can only be used within a data step or in a macro definition that gets called inside of a data step. You can't have it out in open code.

if `%trim()` existed, which it does not, it would work just fine the way you used it. But, there is no function named `%trim()` that is defined in the SAS macro language.

Doing what you want without `%sysfunc()`, would have to go something like:

```
data _NULL_;
    call symput("x", trim("&num."));
run;
```

or if you want `x` to be a data set variable:

```
%let expr= trim("&num.");

DATA ds;
    x = &expr.;
RUN;
```